# setvbuf и кириллица

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmd, utf-8, кириллица

Столкнулся с интересным поведением функции setvbuf при работе с кириллицей. **Вопрос: почему такой код не может вывести кириллицу**
(text приходит через cURL запрос в кодировке utf-8)

```
int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    char text [512] {};
    cout << text << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Результат]

**а такой же, но со строчкой setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IOFBF, 2) уже может**

```
int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    setvbuf(stdout, nullptr, _IOFBF, 2);
    char text [512] {};
    cout << text << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дебаггер показывает, что перегрузка для cout используется одинаковая и в первом и во втором случае.